# There is no data in my listadapter while fetching from SQLITE db

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to android programming and I want to make my database for products. I followed the tutorial but still I got some errors but I fixed them but this is my biggest problem so far. When I enter a data it just says "Data added successfully!" But there is nothing in my list adapter.

Here's my databaseHandler

```
    private static final  String prodID = "ID ";
    private static final String PRODNAME = "ProdName";
    private static final String CATEGORY = "Category";

    public DatabaseHANDLER(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable  = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + prodID + " String primary key," + PRODNAME + " text not null,"
                + CATEGORY + " text not null);";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }



    public  boolean NewData (String PROD_ID, String prodNAME,String Category) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(prodID, PROD_ID);
        values.put(PRODNAME, prodNAME);
        values.put(CATEGORY, Category);


        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public Cursor getListContents() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
   }
```

Here's when I want to add new data

```
    prodID = findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        PROD_NAME =  findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        CATEGORY =  findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        btnAdd =  findViewById(R.id.btnAdd) ;
        db = new DatabaseHANDLER(this);

        Button btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String product_ID = prodID.getText().toString();
                String prod_name = PROD_NAME.getText().toString();
                String category = CATEGORY.getText().toString();


                if(prod_name.length() != 0 && product_ID.length() != 0 && category.length() != 0){

                    NewData(product_ID,prod_name, category);
                    prodID.setText(" ");
                    PROD_NAME.setText(" ");
                    CATEGORY.setText(" ");



                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(NewData.this, "Fill the forms completely!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }

            }
        });


    }
    public void NewData(String PROD_ID, String prodNAME,String CATEGORY){
        boolean insertData = db.NewData(PROD_ID, prodNAME, CATEGORY);
        if(insertData == true) {
            Toast.makeText(NewData.this, "Data inserted Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(NewData.this,"Too bad, something went wrong :( ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Here's my list adapter

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ArrayList<Products> products;
private int mViewResourceId;

public ThreeColumn_ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Products> products) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, products);
    this.products = products;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
    Products products1;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_data,parent,false);

    Products products1 = products.get(position);

    if (products != null) {
        TextView ProdID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textProdID);
        TextView ProdName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textProdName);
        TextView Category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textCategory);
        if (ProdID != null) {
            ProdID.setText(products1.getProdID());
        }
        if (ProdName != null) {
            ProdName.setText(products1.getProdNAME());
        }
        if (Category != null) {
            Category.setText((products1.getCategory()));
        }

    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Here is my view data class

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_data);
    databaseHANDLER = new DatabaseHANDLER(this);
    ProductList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor data = databaseHANDLER.getListContents();

    int numrows = data.getCount();
    if (data.getCount() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(viewdata.this, "There is nothing in this database!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{

        int i = 0;
        while (data.moveToNext()){
            products = new Products(data.getString(0),data.getString(1),data.getString(2));
            ProductList.add(i,products);
        }
        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.view_data,ProductList);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: does this check says there is no data? after using the getData function of yours
 if (data.getCount() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(viewdata.this, "There is nothing in this database!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

Comment: After you add data to database, you also need to refresh the list from database and update it in listadapter and notify to redraw list by calling notifydatasetchanged. You are missing refreshing list and notifying part.

Comment: @Rizwan ye it is